# AnyObject? does not have a member named 'subscript' swift

Tags: swift

I am new to swift. I want to get options  in

```
fields: [{ config: { options: [{a: "one", b: "two"}] }}]
```

I have tried the following code but it brings an error
"AnyObject? does not have a member named subscript".

[image: my code]

Comment: Looks like Options is a dictionary. not an array.

Comment: options is array of dictionary.

Comment: so you should cast as [AnyObject]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it works.

```
if let config: AnyObject? = fields[i]["config"] {
          if let options: AnyObject? = config?["options"] {
            println("options : \(options)")
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

`AnyObject?` is really `Optional<AnyObject>`, and subscripts are not defined on the `Optional` type, however, I tried your code with a simulated fields dictionary and I had no issue, so may be your example has context not expressed here? Try making it `... as? AnyObject {` rather than `... as AnyObject! {` to see if that makes any difference. Also, simply quitting and reopening Xcode has shown to fix many of these types of issues :-)

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem just with a project - clean .