# Swift: '(String) -> AnyObject?' does not have a member named 'subscript'

Tags: swift, dictionary, pfuser

I am trying to convert a PFUser (from Parse.com) to a dictionary of [String : AnyObject] type, but I got the following error that seems very confusing to me. I did google search and found the following two SO questions, which, however, still not helpful in solving my problem:

**Error:**

```
'(String) -> AnyObject?' does not have a member named 'subscript'
```

**Found these two posts:**
[relevant SO post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786111/anyobject-does-not-have-a-member-named-subscript-swift), 
[relevant SO post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508044/swift-nsobject-anyobject-does-not-have-a-member-named-subscript)

My PFUser has the keys: **fullName**, **email**, **latitude**, **longitude**, and **linkedInUrl**.

Since the types of the values for the above keys are a mix of String and Double. so I am trying to create the following Dictionary:

```
var userData : [String: AnyObject] = [
            "fullName" : pfUser.valueForKey("fullName") as? String,
            "latitude" : pfUser.valueForKey("latitude") as? Double,
            "longitude" : pfUser.valueForKey("longitude") as? Double,
            "email" : pfUser.valueForKey("email") as? String,
            "linkedInUrl" : pfUser.valueForKey["linkedInUrl"] as? String
        ]
```

The version of my XCode is 6.4. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring wrong type of `userData`. It must be `[String: AnyObject?]` because your values are optionals.

And don't forget to change this line `"linkedInUrl" : pfUser.valueForKey["linkedInUrl"] as? String`  with this line `"linkedInUrl" : pfUser.valueForKey("linkedInUrl") as? String`.

And your code will be:

```
var userData : [String: AnyObject?] = [
        "fullName" : pfUser.valueForKey("fullName") as? String,
        "latitude" : pfUser.valueForKey("latitude") as? Double,
        "longitude" : pfUser.valueForKey("longitude") as? Double,
        "email" : pfUser.valueForKey("email") as? String,
        "linkedInUrl" : pfUser.valueForKey("linkedInUrl") as? String
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in your current code

First one is, use `( )` instead of using `[ ]` to get the value using the key in the following line.

`"linkedInUrl" : pfUser.valueForKey["linkedInUrl"] as? String`

Second one is, use an exclamation point instead to unwrap the optional.

Your code should look like what's shown below.

```
var userData : [String: AnyObject] = [
   "fullName" : pfUser.valueForKey("fullName") as! String,
   "latitude" : pfUser.valueForKey("latitude") as! Double,
   "longitude" : pfUser.valueForKey("longitude") as! Double,
   "email" : pfUser.valueForKey("email") as! String,
   "linkedInUrl" : pfUser.valueForKey("linkedInUrl") as! String
]
```

The other solution is, making the dictionary declaration as `[String: AnyObject?]` to hold the optional values.